# What is EOF , EOJ or that things used for in php?

Tags: php

I found couple of times in php codes during my work now, something that looks like following:

```
<?

...

echo <<<EOF
{\$sErrors} <br />
Please go to the <br />
<a href="http://www.website.com/help_center">Help center</a> <br />
and solve the problem.
EOF;

...

?>
```

Does anyone have a good answer???

Comment: did i make question about to ask me if google gone bankrupt or whatever?

Comment: Seems not... https://www.google.com/search?q=eof%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp still lots of cash in the bank, phew.

Comment: @ΔημητρηςΘεοδωριδης: no, but you asked a question that Google could have answered within seconds if you even bothered to try.

Comment: **From 0 to 60** in (0.14 seconds) actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a way of entering multi-line strings, it's called the [`heredoc syntax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: without quotes around it? anyways, do you know for EOJ? And thanks of course!

Comment: It's the same. You can choose the text you want to use to delimit it.

Comment: Did you check out the link Dominic provided. All the answers are there.

Comment: oh yes thank i forgot for that! thanks guys!